# TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object. while removing a div

Tags: javascript

am trying to remove a div and i get this error in the console. the div is creating well, even when i go to inspect element it is there and it is passing the div name to the remove function.

```js
function removeRow(input) {
  //$("#".input).remove();
    var d = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
var d_nested = document.getElementById(input);
var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
  }
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">

    <div id="div2" class="row">
        <label>
            the first element
            <label>
                <a onclick="removeRow(div2)" style="float:right" title="Remove Drug">X  </a>
            </label>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="row">
        <label>
            the Second element
            <label>
                <a onclick="removeRow(div3)" style="float:right" title="Remove Drug">X  </a>
            </label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

after i click the x i get this error in the console
TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.

Comment: You need to pass a string in removeRow('div2') to make getElementById() successfull.

Comment: yep, you are passing a varriable which doesnt exsist and not the string value `'div2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why does it not work?

You need to pass a string in removeRow('div2') to make getElementById(input) successfull.

### Small example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function removeRow(input){
                var d = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
                var d_nested = document.getElementById(input); //getElementById() expectes as string as parameter, not an undefined
                var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'parentDiv'>
            <div id = 'div2'>
                <a onclick = "removeRow('div2')">X  </a>
            </div>
            <div id = 'div3'>
                <a onclick = "removeRow('div3')">Y  </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Improvements

It is good practice to split markup and functionality. Furthermore we can skip the passing of id and make it more expendable.

On this example we identify all links by a class and all its containers which we wish to remove by another class. Like this we are independent on the dom levels between them.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //We are assigning the javascript function to the html
            //For this we assigned a class to all elements (anyClass) to find those more efficiently.
            function Init(){
                //We are getting all anyClass elements
                var tL = document.querySelectorAll('.anyClass');

                //We assign the remove event for all of them and instead of the string id we pass the element itself (=this)
                for(var i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++)
                    tL[i].onclick = function(){
                        removeRow(this)
                    }
            }

            //input:=element and not string id anymore
            function removeRow(input){
                //Now we are getting the parent for the input element, marked as anyRow so we do not rely on fixed dom structure
                //Furthermore we do not need to retrieve parentDiv anymore
                var tP = function getParent(e){return (e.className.indexOf('anyRow') !== -1 || !e.parentNode) ? e : getParent(e.parentNode)}(input);

                if (tP) tP.parentNode.removeChild(tP)
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'Init()'>
        <div id = 'parentDiv'>
            <div id = 'div2' class = 'anyRow'><a class = 'anyClass'>X</a></div>
            <div id = 'div3' class = 'anyRow'><a class = 'anyClass'>Y</a></div>
            <div id = 'div4' class = 'anyRow'><a class = 'anyClass'>Z</a></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this solves the issue, it does not provide an efficient solution to the answer. You should address that inline events are not good practice, and not introduce a static string to the events. Using the native DOM prop `this` would provide a more dynamic approach to this.

Comment: An answer simply fixes mistakes. A great answer goes above and beyond to teach good practice.